# How to implement pushwoosh with ionic 2

Tags: push-notification, ionic2, cordova-plugins, pushwoosh

I want to implement pushwoosh in ionic 2 i am using [this](https://github.com/Pushwoosh/pushwoosh-phonegap-plugin) cordova plugin. i am new to ionic 2 want to know how to use methods from this plugin.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First read the pushwoosh manual about using the cordova plugin: http://docs.pushwoosh.com/docs/cordova-phonegap

After that i got this code working on ios and android.

On step 3, you can use the following code as a service provider:
in my projects folder i created this file: /src/app/providers/push-service.ts

```
import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";
import { Platform } from 'ionic-angular';
declare var cordova : any;

@Injectable()
export class PushService {

    PUSHWOOSH_APP_ID : string =  'XXXXX-XXXXX'; // your pushwoosh app id
    GOOGLE_PROJECT_NUMBER: string = 'XXXXXXXXXXXX'; // project number from firebase

    constructor(public platform : Platform){

        this.platform.ready().then(() => {
            if(this.platform.is('ios') || this.platform.is('android')){
                console.log("PushwooshService init: Running on push compatible platform "+ this.platform.userAgent() +')');
                this.initPushwoosh();
            } else{
                console.log("PushwooshService init: No compatible platform available.  Skipping init.)");
                return;
            }
        });


    }

    initPushwoosh(){
        let pushNotification = cordova.require("pushwoosh-cordova-plugin.PushNotification");

          //set push notifications handler
          document.addEventListener('push-notification', function (event) {
            let message = (event as any).notification.message; // Push message
            let userData = (event as any).notification.userdata; // Custom push data

            if (userData) {
            // handle custom push data here
            console.log('user data: ' + JSON.stringify(userData));
            }

          });

          //initialize Pushwoosh with projectid: "GOOGLE_PROJECT_NUMBER", pw_appid : "PUSHWOOSH_APP_ID". This will trigger all pending push notifications on start.
          pushNotification.onDeviceReady({
              appid: this.PUSHWOOSH_APP_ID,
              projectid: this.GOOGLE_PROJECT_NUMBER
              // serviceName: "MPNS_SERVICE_NAME"
          });

          //register for pushes
          pushNotification.registerDevice(
              function (status) {
                var pushToken = status;
                console.log(pushToken);
                alert('push token: ' + JSON.stringify(pushToken));
              },
              function (status) {
                alert(JSON.stringify(['failed to register ', status]));
              }
          );
    }

}
```

Now you can import this provider in your /src/app/app.component.ts.

```
    import { PushService } from '../providers/push-service';

    @Component({
      templateUrl: 'app.html',
      providers: [PushService]
    })
```

Whenever your app is launched, it will initialize pushwoosh.

Good luck ;)

Comment: Is it compulsory to use project number from firebase? because i am using a mySQL database instead.

Comment: For android you need a firebase project number for Cloud messaging, to send notifications.

Comment: Thanks it really helps me alot!!
But i am still getting error on event.notification.message. Can you please explain me from where 'notification' variable comes from? My intellisense showing a red line on notification!

Comment: I am always getting 'ERROR: Method 'onDeviceReady:' not defined in Plugin 'PushNotification' do you know why this is happening?

Comment: @nareeboy Did you follow the steps provided by http://docs.pushwoosh.com/docs/cordova-phonegap and install the plugin correctly? Otherwise i Need some more information about your code.

Comment: @RamshaS , sorry to react so late. Have you figured it out yet, if not, i changed the code a little to prevent this from happening.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use

```js
var message = (event as any).notification.message;
```

Instead of

```js
var message = event.notification.message;
```