# How to implement pushwoosh in ionic 3

Tags: ionic3, pushwoosh

I am aware of [ionic 1](https://www.pushwoosh.com/v1.0/docs/cordova-phonegap) 
but I want to know how to implement Pushwoosh in ionic 3.

Any idea how?

Comment: Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/43516143/7689896

Comment: thanks for ur reply, i already success for register device, but when i try to create message use api with [this](https://cp.pushwoosh.com/json/1.3/createMessage) i get error that tell SENDER_ID_MISMATCH